# Forcing zero subset sums in zero characteristic

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$
A problem from the year 2003 Miklos Schweitzer exam (see also [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/251835/9924)) goes, essentially, as follows:

If $b_1,\dotsc,b_k\in\mathbb F_p^n$ are vectors with $b_1^\perp\cup\dotsb\cup b_k^\perp=\mathbb F_p^n$ (meaning that every vector from $\mathbb F_p^n$ is orthogonal to at least one of the vectors $b_i$), then there exist $\ve_1,\dotsc,\ve_k\in\{0,1\}$ not all equal to $0$ such that $\ve_1b_1+\dotsb+\ve_kb_k=0$.

> What is the zero-characteristic analogue of this fact? Are there any reasonable assumptions that guarantee the existence of not-all-zero $\ve_1,\dotsc,\ve_k\in\{0,1\}$ with $\ve_1b_1+\dotsb+\ve_kb_k=0$, say, over the reals?

Notice that for a vector space $V$ over a zero-characteristic field, the assumption $b_1^\perp\cup\dotsc\cup b_k^\perp=V$ becomes totally unreasonable (simply meaning that one of the vectors $b_i$ is $0$).